# Passing a variable into :contains selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

```
window.something.updateStatus = function(theName) {
  $('#myTable').children('tr').remove(":contains('theName')");
};
```

Obviously the above does not work because it is looking for a string called "theName" in any  in myTable.

What I'd like to do is pass in theName's Value to the contains.

How do I evaluate this expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is untested, but should work:

```
window.something.updateStatus = function(theName) {
  $('#myTable').children('tr').remove(":contains('" + theName +"')");
};
```

Essentially it removes the variable `theName` from the string, but still quotes that value (once the variable's interpolated), which is why there's an opening, and closing, `'` either side of the variable and `+` concatenation operators.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. the double/single quote combination threw me off! Thanks.

Comment: And we should offer the usual caveat: that if `theName` string ever happened to contain a single quote inside, that jQuery would not be able to parse the selector and would raise an error.